# PyTorch - discard dataloader batch

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I have a custom `Dataset` that loads data from large files. Sometimes, the loaded data are empty and I don't want to use them for training.

In `Dataset` I have:

```
   def __getitem__(self, i):
       (x, y) = self.getData(i) #getData loads data and handles problems     
       return (x, y)
```

which in case of bad data return `(None, None)` (`x` and `y` are both `None`). However, it later fails in `DataLoader` and I am not able to skip this batch entirely. I have the batch size set to `1`.

```
trainLoader = DataLoader(trainDataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
for x_batch, y_batch in trainLoader:
    #process and train
```

Comment: Can you not preprocess those missing files out of your dataset instead of doing it at runtime?

Comment: @Ivan It can be the solution, but it is quite time-consuming to pre-process the entire dataset.  Plus for the future, I can have data loaded from the network which I dont have before. So am looking for runtime-based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a custom [`IterableDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset) and define a `__next__` and `__iter__` that would skip any instances for which your `getData` function has raised an error on:

Here is a possible implementation with dummy data:

```
class DS(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = torch.randint(0,3,(20,))
        self._i = -1

    def getData(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        if x == 0:
            raise ValueError
        return x

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self._i += 1
        if self._i == len(self.data):  # out of instances
            self._i = -1               # reset the iterable
            raise StopIteration        # stop the iteration
        try:
            return self.getData(self._i)
        except ValueError:
            return next(self)
```

---

You would use it like:

```
>>> trainLoader = DataLoader(DS(), batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
>>> for x in trainLoader:
...    print(x)
tensor([1])
tensor([2])
tensor([2])
...
tensor([1])
tensor([1])
```

Here all `0` instances have been skipped in the iterable dataset.

You can adapt this simple example to fit your needs.